Why would any adult "gasp, as a child declared that Sandra est la mère de Cendrillon"?
Peut-on expliquer la dernière affirmation dans cette réponse à une autre question ?
Pourquoi elle causerait l'ahurissement chez les adultes ?

As an example of how spelling matters and influences our thinking: I
have witnessed once several French adults gasp, as a child declared
that Sandra est la mère de Cendrillon. The child correctly noticed the
phonetic similarity, but was unaware of different (etymological)
spelling.


The sentence following your quote explains it : "The child correctly noticed the phonetic similarity, but was unaware of different (etymological) spelling." The first syllable of Sandra and Cendrillon are pronounced: [sɑ̃dʀ] although the spelling is different (a child who can't read & spell properly yet can't know). The suffix "illon" being a diminutive suffix (and a smart child can have noticed that even if they can't read or spell (botte/bottillon, oiseau/oisillon etc.), adding illon to Sandra turns [sɑ̃.dʀijɔ̃]  into a "small Sandra" (i.e. her daughter).

That's a clever remark from the child, and unusual enough to astonish a lot of adults who don't think about it since they know both, etymology & spelling.  In fact your question is not really a proper question, it should really be asked in a comment to RogerV.'s answer.  So I'd rather let @RogerV. answer you since it is their anecdote.

@None You wrote "it should really be asked in a comment to RogerV.'s answer." But I can't comment to  RogerV.'s answer. I don't have 50 reputation.

Quite right, fair enough. Maybe you could have phrased the question differently, still referring to RogerV.'s answer. Are you asking why people are astonished (which at the bottom is subjective and not fit for a question on FL)? – answered in my second comment. Is your problem identifying the phonetic similarity between Sandra and Cendrillon (which is objective and can be answered (even if some might object it can be checked in a dictionary)? – answered in my 1st comment.

@None vous avez ma permission et mon approbation pour reformuler ma question.
mon problème est "identifying the phonetic similarity between Sandra and Cendrillon (which is objective and can be answered".

The French names Sandra [sɑ̃dʀa] and Cendrillon [sɑ̃dʀijɔ̃] begin with the same sounds.
In French illon is a diminutive suffix.
A child who can't read and spell properly yet can't know that what they hear as [sɑ̃dʀ] is spelt differently in each name, but being smart and having a good command of the spoken language they can make an aural connection between the two female names and knowing common words like botillon (a small boot, from botte),  oisillon (a baby bird, from oiseau) they think that adding illon to Sandra turns her into "small Sandra", that is to say her daughter.
That's a clever remark from a child, and unusual enough to astonish a lot of adults who don't think about it since adults know both, etymology and spelling.
